# Создание default-метода через ow2 asm

Tags: java, jvm

Хочу создать default-метод, который вызывает другой метод в этом интерфейсе. Указываю модификатор доступа `ACC_PUBLIC`, но JVM не может прочитать этот класс: `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method ... in class ... has illegal modifiers: 0x1`.

Однако если записать этот класс в файл и декомпилировать его, то этот метод спокойно читается через декомпилятор

[image]

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Вот код который у меня есть:

```java
    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(
            final int access,
            final String name,
            final String descriptor,
            final String signature,
            final String[] exceptions
    ) {
        val methodSignature = signature == null
                ? Signatures.readMethodSignature(descriptor)
                : Signatures.readMethodSignature(signature);

        if (target.matches(methodSignature, name)) {
            val stackSize = AsmUtils.countStackSize(methodSignature.getParameterTypes());

            val renamedMethod = visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, renameTo,
                    descriptor, signature, exceptions);

            renamedMethod.visitCode();
            renamedMethod.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);

            int pos = 1;

            for (val parameterType : methodSignature.getParameterTypes()) {
                pos = AsmUtils.writeLoad(pos, parameterType.getName(), renamedMethod);
            }

            renamedMethod.visitMethodInsn(isInterface
                    ? Opcodes.INVOKEINTERFACE
                    : Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, this.name, name, descriptor, false);
            AsmUtils.writeReturn(methodSignature.getReturnType().getName(), renamedMethod);

            renamedMethod.visitMaxs(stackSize + 1, stackSize + 1);
            renamedMethod.visitEnd();
        }

        return super.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается класс, который я собирался изменить, был скомпилирован на версии 1.6, где ещё не поддерживались default-методы. Помогло изменение версии класса на 1.8.